# Как увеличить размер окна videowidget'a в pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Есть код в котором есть 3 иконки  после нажатия на иконку видеоплеера открывается окно с видеоплеером а картинка маленькая, то есть как сделать остальные виджеты поверх видео виджета?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, \
QSlider, QStyle, QSizePolicy, QFileDialog, QAction, qApp, QMainWindow
import sys
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5 import  QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase


class Example(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent = None):

    super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)

    self.setWindowTitle("Media Player")
    self.setGeometry(350, 100, 700, 500)
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('F:/img_4_python/mediaplayer.png'))

    self.secondWin = None

    self.threeWin = None

    self.initUI()

    self.show()


def initUI(self):

    hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    exitAction = QAction(QIcon('F:/img_4_python/exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
    exitAction.setShortcut('Alt+F4')
    exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
    

    videoAction = QAction(QIcon('F:/img_4_python/video.png'), 'Play Video', self)
    videoAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
    videoAction.triggered.connect(self.openvideo)


    musicAction = QAction(QIcon('F:/img_4_python/mp3.png'), 'Play Song', self)
    musicAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')
    musicAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

    self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Toolbar')
    self.toolbar.setMovable(False)
    self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)
    self.toolbar.addAction(videoAction)
    self.toolbar.addAction(musicAction)

def openvideo(self):
    if not self.secondWin:
        self.secondWin = SecondWindow(self)
    self.secondWin.show()

class SecondWindow(QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)

    self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Media Player")
    self.setGeometry(350, 100, 700, 500)
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('player.png'))

    self.setStyleSheet(("""background-color: #000;
                            """ ))

    self.init_ui()


    self.show()


def init_ui(self):

    # add new font to the QFont database
    id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('F:/Fonts for pyqt5/Google.ttf')

    #create media player object
    self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)


    #create videowidget object

    videowidget = QVideoWidget()


    #create open button
    openBtn = QPushButton('Open Video')
    openBtn.setStyleSheet(("""background-color: #fff;
                            font: 14pt "Google";
                            """ ))
    openBtn.clicked.connect(self.open_file)



    #create button for playing
    self.playBtn = QPushButton()
    self.playBtn.setEnabled(False)
    self.playBtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
    self.playBtn.clicked.connect(self.play_video)



    #create slider
    self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
    self.slider.setRange(0,0)
    self.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.set_position)



    #create label
    self.label = QLabel()
    self.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Maximum)


    #create hbox layout
    hboxLayout = QHBoxLayout()
    hboxLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

    #set widgets to the hbox layout
    hboxLayout.addWidget(openBtn)
    hboxLayout.addWidget(self.playBtn)
    hboxLayout.addWidget(self.slider)



    #create vbox layout
    vboxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    vboxLayout.addWidget(videowidget)
    vboxLayout.addLayout(hboxLayout)
    vboxLayout.addWidget(self.label)


    self.setLayout(vboxLayout)

    self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videowidget)


    #media player signals

    self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediastate_changed)
    self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.position_changed)
    self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.duration_changed)


def open_file(self):
    filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Video")

    if filename != '':
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)))
        self.playBtn.setEnabled(True)


def play_video(self):
    if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
        self.mediaPlayer.pause()

    else:
        self.mediaPlayer.play()


def mediastate_changed(self, state):
    if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
        self.playBtn.setIcon(
            self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause)

        )

    else:
        self.playBtn.setIcon(
            self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay)

        )

def position_changed(self, position):
    self.slider.setValue(position)


def duration_changed(self, duration):
    self.slider.setRange(0, duration)


def set_position(self, position):
    self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)


def handle_errors(self):
    self.playBtn.setEnabled(False)
    self.label.setText("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())




if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо почитать https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, \
    QSlider, QStyle, QSizePolicy, QFileDialog, QAction, qApp, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5 import  QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase


class SecondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)

        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Media Player")
        self.setGeometry(350, 100, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('player.png'))

        self.setStyleSheet(("""background-color: #000;
                                """ ))
        self.init_ui()
#        self.show()

    def init_ui(self):
        # add new font to the QFont database
        id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('F:/Fonts for pyqt5/Google.ttf')

        #create media player object
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

        #create videowidget object
        videowidget = QVideoWidget()

        #create open button
        openBtn = QPushButton('Open Video')
        openBtn.setStyleSheet(("""background-color: #fff;
                                font: 14pt "Google";
                                """ ))
        openBtn.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        #create button for playing
        self.playBtn = QPushButton()
        self.playBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.playBtn.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playBtn.clicked.connect(self.play_video)

        #create slider
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setRange(0,0)
        self.slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.set_position)

        #create label
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        #create hbox layout
        hboxLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        hboxLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        #set widgets to the hbox layout
        hboxLayout.addWidget(openBtn)
        hboxLayout.addWidget(self.playBtn)
        hboxLayout.addWidget(self.slider)

        #create vbox layout
        vboxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vboxLayout.addWidget(videowidget)
        vboxLayout.addLayout(hboxLayout)
        vboxLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(vboxLayout)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videowidget)

        #media player signals
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediastate_changed)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.position_changed)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.duration_changed)

    def open_file(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Video")
        if filename != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)))
            self.playBtn.setEnabled(True)

    def play_video(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediastate_changed(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playBtn.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause)
            )
        else:
            self.playBtn.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay)
            )

    def position_changed(self, position):
        self.slider.setValue(position)

    def duration_changed(self, duration):
        self.slider.setRange(0, duration)

    def set_position(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handle_errors(self):
        self.playBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.label.setText("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                                        # +++
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                             # +++
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)                           # +++
        

        self.setWindowTitle("Media Player")
        self.setGeometry(350, 100, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('im.png')) #('F:/img_4_python/mediaplayer.png'))

        self.secondWin = None
        self.threeWin = None

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#         hbox = QHBoxLayout()

#        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('F:/img_4_python/exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('img/exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Alt+F4')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

#        videoAction = QAction(QIcon('F:/img_4_python/video.png'), 'Play Video', self)
        videoAction = QAction(QIcon('im.png'), 'Play Video', self)
        videoAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        videoAction.triggered.connect(self.openvideo)

#        musicAction = QAction(QIcon('F:/img_4_python/mp3.png'), 'Play Song', self)
        musicAction = QAction(QIcon('Ok.png'), 'Play Song', self)
        musicAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')
        musicAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Toolbar')
        self.toolbar.setMovable(False)
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(videoAction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(musicAction)

    def openvideo(self):
        if not self.secondWin:
            self.secondWin = SecondWindow(self)
#        self.secondWin.show()                                        # ---
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.secondWin)                           # +++

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]